# Owl carousel with mouse wheel scroll plugin speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, mousewheel

I'm using `Owl Carousel 2` along the `Mouse Wheel` plugin as the website shows how to implement it:
https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/mousewheel.html

Here is my example: https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/

This is my code:

```
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
  if (e.deltaY>0) {
      owl.trigger('next.owl');
  } else {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem I have is that the scroll it's not smooth, it is very fast and scrolls through 6-10 slides at once which it's not useable.
I want it to be as smooth as the mouse wheel scroll as posible.

I have find a lightbox plugin that integrates the mousewheel plugin and checked how they do it but I just don't know how to use that with my code, can you help me with it?

This is the plugin: http://fancybox.net

You can check on the `Image gallery (ps, try using mouse scroll wheel)`  popup gallery example.

If you download the plugin it, you can see that they implemented Mouse Wheel plugin this way:

```
if ($.fn.mousewheel) {
    wrap.bind('mousewheel.fb', function(e, delta) {
        if (busy) {
            e.preventDefault();

        } else if ($(e.target).get(0).clientHeight == 0 || $(e.target).get(0).scrollHeight === $(e.target).get(0).clientHeight) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fancybox[ delta > 0 ? 'prev' : 'next']();
        }
    });
}
```

Can you help me to make it work correctly with Owl Carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use smartSpeed function to set the scrolling speed.

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html

```js
var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  loop:true,
  margin:0,
  nav:true,
  smartSpeed:1000,
  responsive:{
      0:{
          items:1
      },
      600:{
          items:1
      },
      1000:{
          items:1
      }
  }
});
owl.on('mousewheel', '.owl-stage', function (e) {
  if (e.deltaY>0) {
      owl.trigger('next.owl');
  } else {
      owl.trigger('prev.owl');
  }
  e.preventDefault();
});
$(document,window,'html').mouseleave(function(){
  $("#footer").fadeOut();
}).mouseenter(function(){
  $("#footer").fadeIn();
});
$(function(){
  $("#header").load("includes/header.html");
  $("#footer").load("includes/footer.html");
});
```

```css
body { padding-top: 0px;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/css/main.css">

  <header id="header"></header>

  <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url(https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/img/carousel-3-ux.png)"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url(https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/img/carousel-4-editorial.png)"></div>
    <div class="item" style="background-image:url(https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/img/carousel-5-senaletica.png)"></div>
  </div>

  <footer id="footer"></footer>

  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/vendor/modernizr-3.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/jquery.justifiedGallery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://z-testing.000webhostapp.com/_owlcarousel/app/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks but it if you check your snippet it doesn't work at all, still does the same behavior.